# How to justify Strings in java as reference type? check out the following cases

Tags: java, string, value-type, reference-type

Case 1:

```
        String s1 = "Hello";
        String s2 = s1; //now has the same reference as s1 right?

        System.out.println(s1); //prints Hello
        System.out.println(s2); //prints Hello

        s1 = "hello changed"; //now changes s2 (so s1 as well because of the same reference?) to  Hello changed

        System.out.println(s1); //prints Hello changed 
        System.out.println(s2); //prints Hello  (why isn't it changed to  Hello changed?)
```

output of this case is obvious.

Case 2:

```
        String s1 = "Hello";
        String s2 = s1; //now has the same reference as s1 right?

        System.out.println(s1); //prints Hello
        System.out.println(s2); //prints Hello

        s2 = "hello changed"; //now changes s2 (so s1 as well because of the same reference?) to  Hello changed

        System.out.println(s1); //prints Hello (why isn't it changed to Hello changed?)
        System.out.println(s2); //prints Hello changed
```

I want to clear the confusion of reference type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Let me clear all the above cases for you.

**Case 1:**

when you created `String s1 = "Hello";`, the compiler first places the `String` value `"Hello"` in the memory location and stores the reference of that memory location to variable `s1`. So your variable `s1` has what? only the reference of `"Hello"`. So `s1` does not contain `Hello` instead it's memory location as reference. Done?

Then when you declare `String s2 = s1;`, you only store the reference of `Hello` to `s2` not the reference of `s1` variable itself because `s1` had the reference of `"Hello"` nothing else. Then when you are printing both `s1` and `s2` they both are printing `"Hello"` because they both contain the reference of `"Hello"`.

When you declare `s1 = "hello changed";`, `s1` has no more the reference of `"Hello"` now, instead it contains the reference of `String` value `"hello changed"` which is in a different memory location. But still `s2` has the reference of `String` value `"Hello"` because you did not assign anything to `s2` yet. So now `s1` has the reference of `"hello changed"` and `s2` has the reference of `"Hello"`. If you print `s1` and `s2`, they will print their corresponding `String` values `"hello changed"` and '"Hello"`. Are you clear now? if not yet see below code samples:

```
String s1 = "Hello"; // s1 has reference of "Hello"
String s2 = s1; // Now s2 has reference of "Hello" not s1

System.out.println(s1); // Prints "Hello"
System.out.println(s2); // Prints "Hello"

s1 = "hello changed"; // Now s1 has reference of "hello changed" not "Hello" but still s2 has reference of "Hello" because you did not changed it.

System.out.println(s1); // Prints "hello changed" 
System.out.println(s2); // Prints "Hello" because you did not changed it.
```

***Case 2:***

```
String s1 = "Hello"; // s1 has reference of "Hello"
String s2 = s1; // Now s2 has reference of "Hello" not s1

System.out.println(s1); // Prints "Hello"
System.out.println(s2); // Prints "Hello"

s2 = "hello changed"; // Now s1 has reference of "hello changed" not "Hello" but still s2 has reference of "Hello" because you did not changed it.

System.out.println(s1); // Prints "Hello" because you did not changed it.
System.out.println(s2); // Prints "hello changed" because you changed it.
```

If you are still confused, do not forget to comment it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After

```
String s2 = s1;
```

both `s2` and `s1` hold a reference to the same `String`.

But after

```
s2 = "hello changed";
```

`s2` holds a reference to a new `String`, while `s1` still holds a reference to the original `String`.

`String`s are immutable, so you can't change the state of an existing `String` object. Assigning a new value to a `String` variable simply makes that variable reference a new `String` object. The original `String` object is unaffected.

Comment: understood. how to say Strings in java are reference types? can you give me an example?

Comment: @TarunDadlani What do you mean by "how to say"? `String`s are reference types since `String` is a class. All classes and interfaces in Java are reference types.

Comment: i know it is working with classes but not with String. you've seen both the cases

Comment: @TarunDadlani String is a class, so I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean that due to the immutability of Strings you can't demonstrate that changing the state of an Object affects all the variables holding references to it?